# ClassNotFoundException with Freemarker

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

sorry for my noobie question, but I can't figure it out.

I have an application running on GAE, with Spring MVC and I am trying to add Free Marker as templating language.

In my pom.xml, I have:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
 <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
 <version>2.3.20</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, in my dispatcher config, I have configured freemarker view resolver like this:

```
<!-- freemarker config -->
<bean id="freemarkerConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
</bean>

<!-- View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. 
    If you need different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the 
    resource bundle resolver. -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".ftl" />
</bean>
```

When I start the webserver with Eclipse, I get a classnotfound exception (see below), but I cannot figure out what's missing and how to add it =(

Would you please help me?

Thanks!

```
2013-11-07 17:30:17.097:WARN::Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer] for bean with name 'freemarkerConfig' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory|Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer] for bean with name 'freemarkerConfig' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/freemarker/FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the `spring-context-support` to your project. Add this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```